# Freebsd - only install gnome desktop (only minimal ports needed)

Tags: gnome, freebsd

Is there a way to only install the gnome desktop? I don't want all these extra things... I'll install it manually if I need it. Also, why do we need xorg? My VM has been running for a while (installing), haven't gotten any problems yet.

Answer (score 0):

gnome runs on top of xorg. There is a port called gnome2-lite which should install only the required components